# I keep getting the error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function"

Tags: web3js, truffle

I have tested it in remix and the function does work, I also removed inputs just for testing purposes but it seems that it doesn't work anyway.

Here is the function:

```
struct Message{
    string Message;
    int Vote;
    uint timeSubmit;
    bool isImportant;
    uint senderId;
}
Message[] messageArr; 
function getMessageString() public view returns(string memory){
        return messageArr[2].Message;
    }
```

I am calling it in web3.js like this:

```
  function getString() {
        messageInstance.getMessageString(function(error, result){
          if (error) {
              console.log(error)
          }
          else {
        console.log("yes")

      }})
    }
```

I am using truffle but it keeps giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `getMessageString` takes 0 parameters, yet you are calling it with 1 parameter.

Therefore, change this:

```
messageInstance.getMessageString(function(error, result)
```

To something like this:

```
messageInstance.getMessageString().then(function(result)
```